# Paging in the list

Tags: windows-phone-8, paging

My second question in Windows Phone App 8.0

How can I achieve paging in the Long List container or any other container
this is how I want to display

- Iteam Head 1

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
- Item Head 2

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3

    Load Next-->

When user click Item Head 3 and Item Head 4 gets loaded. 
I do not want scrolling.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have a master `List<model>` of all items (or items you continually downloading).

Link your Item 1 (I would call it A) and your Item 2 (I would could it B) to the primary list.  Keep track of the location of the Items location in the `List` with a control Index.

Item A and B should be an `ObservableCollection<model>`.  When the user clicks on Load Next -> move the location Index by one (in either direction), clear the `ObservableCollection<model>` and repopulate based on the master `List<model>` this way when you update, the Screen UI element binding will also update.

Comment: That is fine but how will that be displayed in XAML?

Comment: It would only scroll if Item A, B contains more measureable height than the LLS's container height.

Comment: well that is why I do not want to based it on scroll. I will have link provided to move to next set of Item heads (i.e. item head 3 & 4). I can achieve this with the help of two grids but I do not want to go that route

Comment: @Abdul I see what you're trying to do now, the problem is your use cases will conflict with each other.  For example, what if Item 1 has so many sub items that it has more height than the container?  How would you handle this?  You just can't go to Item 2.  The only way I see this being accomplish is that you have fixed size everything, or calculate the height of every sub item whiling inserting it in.

Comment: that is fine, there are not many items. there will be no scroll. In the code behind I have the paging mechanism. However I have trouble arranging it in xaml. Any ideas.

Comment: @Abdul Search Long List Selector Grouping example.